# magento blank first name and last name in billing page

Tags: magento

I am totally lost with the one page checkout system in magento .

I am getting all the values except first name and last name. I can think that it’s a minor fix but cannot trace where the problem is.

Comment: Can you please clarify? The first name and last name input boxes are not showing? Or the first and last name are not coming through when the order is created?

Comment: Hi, sorry to reply late....the boxes are showing but the names are not showing in the billing address block in the right hand panel.The form is posting all the values except first and last name.Really strange.

Comment: Would you mind posting the HTML? It would make it a bit easier to visualise...thanks

Comment: Button code is  <button type="button" title="Continue" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>

Comment: <label for="billing:firstname" class="required"><em>*</em>First Name</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="billing:firstname" name="billing[firstname]" value="" title="First Name" class="input-text required-entry"  />
        </div><label for="billing:lastname" class="required"><em>*</em>Last Name</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="billing:lastname" name="billing[lastname]" value="" title="Last Name" class="input-text required-entry"  />
        </div>

Comment: Is this occurring in all browsers?

Comment: Yes it's happening for all browsers.I think there is something missing with firstname and lastname in the db.Do you know if one page checkout  saves the customer registration details after each step is done in checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating. I had to update my customer folder in my template

if you were using the default template it would be

frontend/base/default/template/customer

Comment: Hi John...can you please let me know what kind of update.Surprisingly its taking middlename surname not first and last name.